# Accessing C typedef structs from DLL in python using ctypes

Tags: python, c, dll, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have some functions written in C which I would like to run in Python and am experiencing some unexpected results trying to access typedef structs. Here is a minimal reproducible example. Ultimately my question is how to access a global c structure stored in the shared library within the python code, or the typedef defined in the header file to recreate the same structure in python. Perhaps the method I am using to compile the SO file does not create the global variables?:

temp.c file:

```
#include "temp.h"
 

aStruct_t aStruct = {0};


extern void AdderFunction(aStruct_t *struct1, int num)
{
    struct1->y = struct1->x;
    struct1->x += num;
}
```

temp.h file

```
#ifndef _TEMP_H_

#define _TEMP_H_
    
#include <stdint.h>
    
typedef struct aStruct_t
{
        uint32_t x;
        uint32_t y;
        uint32_t z;

} aStruct_t;


extern void AdderFunction(aStruct_t *struct1, int num);

#endif
```

Which I compiled into an so file:

```
gcc -shared -o temp.so -fPIC temp.c
```

I would like to be able to access the C structure `aStruct`  in python

e.g.

```
import ctypes
so_file = "../temp.so"
tempLib = ctypes.CDLL(so_file)
tempLib.aStruct.y
```

but get the error  `AttributeError: '_FuncPtr' object has no attribute 'y'`

I am surprised that the typedef structure is of type function pointer? Why is this?

I can work around the problem by creating a similar structure in python however this is undesirable since I have several quite large typedef structures in the C code and every time I update the structure I will then also have to update my python code.

```
import ctypes
so_file = "../temp.so"
tempLib = ctypes.CDLL(so_file)
# tempLib.aStruct.y


class aStruct_python(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x1",ctypes.c_uint),
                ("y1",ctypes.c_uint),
                ("z1",ctypes.c_uint)]

tempLib.AdderFunction(ctypes.pointer(struct_py),2)
```

Comment: What is aStruct supposed to be? Your DLL doesn't have anything in it called aStruct.

Comment: aStruct is an instance of aStruct_t defined as a global variable in the .c file. - I think, as you say, my issue is that when I create the DLL it only brings across the functions and not the global variables. How can you see what is inside the DLL?

Comment: I think the actual problem is that ctypes has no way to know what things are. All the DLL says is "aStruct is at this address" and ctypes assumes it's a function until told otherwise

Answer (score 2):

You can't get away with not declaring the structure.  Only the names of exported C functions and global variables are available from the DLL.

Use `<type>.in_dll()` to access global variables in the DLL.  Attributes of the dll are expected to be the names of exported functions only.

Here's a full example:

**test.c**

```c
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)  // required to export names from MSVC
#else
#   define API
#endif

#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct aStruct_t {
    uint32_t x;
    uint32_t y;
    uint32_t z;
} aStruct_t;

API aStruct_t aStruct = {0};

API void AdderFunction(aStruct_t *struct1, int num) {
    struct1->y = struct1->x;
    struct1->x += num;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

# Must define the structure.
class aStruct(ct.Structure):

    _fields_ = (("x", ct.c_uint32),
                ("y", ct.c_uint32),
                ("z", ct.c_uint32))

    # Define how the structure prints itself
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'aStruct(x={self.x}, y={self.y}, z={self.z})'

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
# Recommended: always fully define arguments and return type.
dll.AdderFunction.argtypes = ct.POINTER(aStruct), ct.c_int
dll.AdderFunction.restype = None

# To access a global variable, call in_dll() on its type,
# passing the DLL instance and the exported global variable name.
a = aStruct.in_dll(dll, 'aStruct')
print(a)

# Declare a local instance of the structure to pass to the function.
s = aStruct(1,2,3)
print(s)

# Call function and print updated structure
dll.AdderFunction(ct.byref(s), 2)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
aStruct(x=0, y=0, z=0)
aStruct(x=1, y=2, z=3)
aStruct(x=3, y=1, z=3)
```